# Does "on-hold" mean you can't flag as duplicate?

Tags: feature-request, duplicates

For some reason, this question doesn't have a flag "as duplicate" option:

[How to run graphical app in background mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/751268/how-to-run-graphical-app-in-background-mode)

It has been put "on-hold" because the user was having a small problem with translation which only became clear once the answer was accepted.   I have revised the question based on the accepted answer, but also need to flag it as duplicate because it's actually a duplicate of this question:

[How to execute a task in background?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/562911/how-to-execute-a-task-in-background?rq=1)

**Is it because it's "on-hold"?  If so, why can I not flag an "on-hold" question as duplicate?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. On Hold is the same as closed - it's labeled as that for the first week to encourage editing.

If it's closed as unclear (and it's still unclear) it cannot be closed as something else.

I don't think the *question* gives me enough info to support a duplicate vote.

My pronouns are He / Him